# In Swift how do I extract a subString from a random String that matches a certain start and end pattern

Tags: swift, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract one or more substrings from a String in SwiftUI that matches a particular pattern.  That pattern is that is starts with 6 digits and ends with a $.

For Example in the string:

```
let str = "Some random text 034503 intermediate text $ some more random text 873234 more intermediate text $."
```

I would like to extract the two substrings:

```
var subString1 = "034503 intermediate text $"
var subString2 = "873234 more intermediate text $"
```

I know how to extract a specific substring, but in this case I don't know the subString.  I only know it begins with a certain pattern (6 digits) and ends with another pattern ($).  How would I go about this?

Comment: What about using a Regex? And your question is not related to SwiftUI, it's just Swift.

Comment: Is it intentional that your second example ends with `&` and not with `$` ?

Comment: sorry, that's a mistype

Comment: The regular expression `[0-9]{6}.*\$` (`"[0-9]{6}.*\\$"` as a Swift string) should work. Or use `\d{6}.*\$` (`"\\d{6}.*\\$"`) if you want to support digits of any language and not just 0-9.

Comment: @HangarRash your regex would also match strings that start with 7 or more digits which i don’t think is what OP wants.

Comment: @HangarRash your regex is also greedy so the `.*` will consume all but the last `$` and result in a single match from the first 6 digits to the last `$`. I think this pattern `\d{6}[^\d$]*\$` will prevent matching more than 6 digits and is non-greedy.

Comment: Hmm. My pattern will fail if there are any digits between the 6 digits and the dollar sign, so that probably isn’t going to work. More examples of what is and isn’t valid could help narrow this down (e.g. will there always be a space after the 6 digits). I think we can all agree that a regular expression is the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
let r = try! Regex("\\b\\d{6} [^$]*\\$")

// or as a regex literal (Swift 5)
let r = /\b\d{6} [^$]*\$/
```

I recommend using something like https://regex101.com to create and validate regular expressions.

Here is your example: https://regex101.com/r/GqCh17/1

Comment: One minor thing, why not use \b after the digits the same way you have before them? This would help if the number was followed by for instance a period or a comma.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's an option. The question is if you want to accept a number like this as valid `034503.123`. Since the OP just gave examples for six digit numbers with spaces after them, I went with that.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess one would have to make the regex even more complex to handle the different variants but most likely your current solution is the most straightforward one given what we know from the question.

Comment: In the `Regex` line you need double backslashes for the Swift string - `"\\b\\d{6} [^$]*\\$"`.

Comment: It needs to be fixed for Swift 5 too (in the string literal, not the regex literal).

Comment: @HangarRash Ah, I thought raw strings would work, but apparently not for regex. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0354-regex-literals.md#escaping-of-backslashes